# Updating the database when double clicking js

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I'm working on a project, and I have an issue. First, let me present a few things to you.

**Database**
*An example on what the database structure looks like*

```
ID    | NAME

1     | Daniel

2     | David
```

**HTML / PHP script**
*What the page itself looks like*

```
<?php
$allUsers = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users");

echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\" style=\"width: 100%;\">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope=\"col\">#</th>
      <th scope=\"col\">Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($allUsers))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class=\"inner\">" . $row['id'] . "</th>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "
</tbody>
</table>";

?>
```

**Javascript code**
*The Javascript code as found on this website as well*

```
    $(function () {
        $(".inner").dblclick(function (e) {
        if($(event.target).attr('class')!="thVal")
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var currentEle = $(this);
                var value = $(this).html();
                updateVal(currentEle, value);
        }
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
        $(document).off('click');
        $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value +     
 '"                 
 />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {

            if($(event.target).attr('class')!="thVal")
            {
                $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
                $(document).off('click');
            }

    });

}
```

Now the first thing I'd like to ask: This does not seem to work on my php page. On my html page on the other hand, where I tried this as well, it does work. What am I doing wrong?

When we've fixed that, how could I make sure that when my user double clicks a value, and changes it, that it updates in the database as well. So, for example, if a user of mine double clicks the value "David" and sets it to "Jeremy", the database will be update to Jeremy as well.

Comment: To add data to database from js you need to use ajax

Comment: How would you suggest to do that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you should distinguish server script and client/ browser script. PHP is server script, when you run this file, it will be compiled to html file. Javascript/ jquery is browser script, it just runs on html file.
2. If you want when my user double clicks a value, and changes it, that it updates in the database as well. You should add more code in javascript/ query:

> ```
> $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
>   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
>     $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
>     // add code here
>     // submit the value to server to update database
>   }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> "This does not seem to work on my php page. On my html page on the
>   other hand, where I tried this as well, it does work"
>
> "if a user of mine double clicks the value "David" and sets it to
>   "Jeremy", the database will be update to Jeremy as well."

Actually both question are related to the same problem. When changing your value with JS you're changing your HTML (front only) but by reloading you'll get the value you had at first... If you want to change your database you'll have to use AJAX as said Litvak. Could be something like this...

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var name = $(".thVal").val();
    var id = // you need to get the ID to be able to change your database at the right row
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
             id : id,
             name : name
        }
        url: 'changeName.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function(data, text) {
             // If change in database worked, do this...
             $(currentEle).html(name);
        }
        error : function(request, status, error) {
             // There was a problem, couldn't change database, do this...
        }
    });

}
```

and your **changeName.php** would be where you run your sql script to change the database...

```
function changeName($id, $name) {
    // make your checks here and your sql call
}

changeName($_POST['id'], $_POST['name']);
```